# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void schedule(String, String, PotentialCustomer) from the type System

Tags: apex, compile-error, scheduled-job

I get this error when I run the below code:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: `void schedule(String, String, PotentialCustomer)` from the type `System`

Code:

```
global class PotentialCustomer implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global string query;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        query =  'select Id,Name from Potential_Customer__c where \'Service__c = 3G\'';
        system.debug('----list of records' + query);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc , list<Potential_Customer__c> scope)
    {
       list<New_Campaign__c> temp = new list<New_Campaign__c>(); 
        for(Potential_Customer__c plist : scope)
        {
           New_Campaign__c nc = new New_Campaign__c();
            nc.Test__c = Potential_Customer__c.Id;
            nc.Name = Potential_Customer__c.Name;
            temp.add(nc);
        }
        insert temp;
    }
```

In Anonymous :

```
PotentialCustomer pc = new PotentialCustomer();
String jobId = System.schedule('jobName', '0 5 * * * ?',pc);
```

Comment: Please put all the code in your class

Answer (score 2):

The `system.schedule` method only accepts a class instance which implements `Schedulable` as its third argument. It's most efficient to just include this implementation detail on your batch itself.

```
public with sharing class MyBatch implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    // batchable implementation below
}
```

**Please note you do not need the `global` access modifier for batches/scheduled jobs. The `public` access modifier will suffice.**

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to schedule your batch apex class. Create a apex class that implement `Schedulable` interface. Once done, schedule that class either from execute anonymous or `Setup->Apex Class-> Schedule apex`

```
global class scheduledAClass implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      PotentialCustomer potentialCusBatch = new PotentialCustomer(); 
      Database.executeBatch(potentialCusBatch);
   }
}
```

Schedule the above class using `execute anonymous` or from `Setup`

Example:

```
scheduledAClass pc = new scheduledAClass();
String sch = '20 30 8 10 2 ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('A Job', sch, pc);
```

References -

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000171199&language=en_US&type=1